# Vision and CoreML – CGImagePropertyOrientation expects wrong type

Tags: swift, arkit, coreml, apple-vision

Currently I am work with ARKit/CoreML/Vision to identify images/objects.

For this purpose I took a look at Apple's sample project [Recognizing and Labeling Arbitrary Objects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_and_labeling_arbitrary_objects)

I have copied the following lines from the *ViewController.Swift* Script into my project:

```
private func classifyCurrentImage() {
    // Most computer vision tasks are not rotation agnostic so it is important 
    // to pass in the orientation of the image with respect to device.
    let orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(UIDevice.current.orientation)
}
```

Here is the constant of type CGImagePropertyOrientation.

When I try to pass device orientation line as a parameter, it gives an error. As CGImagePropertyOrientation expects a value of Type UInt32 and not UIDeviceOrientation

Compiler error output:

```
// Cannot convert value of type 'UIDeviceOrientation' to expected argument type 'UInt32'
```

I think the error is somewhere here *UIDevice.current.orientation*

Answer (score 2):

The first reply of @ibnetariq solves the problem in this code snippet. But i found another solution. The example project contains an extension for CGImagePropertyOrientation which solves my problem.

Code Snippet *Utitlity.swift*

```
import UIKit
import ImageIO

extension CGImagePropertyOrientation {
    /**
     Converts a `UIImageOrientation` to a corresponding
     `CGImagePropertyOrientation`. The cases for each
     orientation are represented by different raw values.
     
     - Tag: ConvertOrientation
     */
    init(_ orientation: UIImageOrientation) {
        switch orientation {
        case .up: self = .up
        case .upMirrored: self = .upMirrored
        case .down: self = .down
        case .downMirrored: self = .downMirrored
        case .left: self = .left
        case .leftMirrored: self = .leftMirrored
        case .right: self = .right
        case .rightMirrored: self = .rightMirrored
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about UInt32 as UIDeviceOrientation is an enum with Int type. I think converting/casting raw value of device orientation into UInt32 would solve your problem.

Try below code

```
CGImagePropertyOrientation(rawValue: UInt32(UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I've tried it and it solves the problem for this code snippet. This causes the following VNImageRequestHandler (not included in the code snippet) to have the problem that the orientation value has to be unwrapped. 

However, I have seen that in the example given by Apple, they have written an extension for CGImagePropertyOrientation, which solves my problem. I write this solution in an extra Answer :-)